# Emailing a Div's contents

Tags: javascript, email, html

I have a div in which it's contents are generated by JavaScript. I was wondering if it is possible to email the contents of the div? Also is it possible in JavaScript or must it be done in PHP?

Comment: Pass the content of the Div back to the server. The mail has to be sent server side; In your case implement this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't email directly from JavaScript in the browser. You need to send the information to a server side (eg. PHP) file.

You can do this using a `form`, but then you need a form field.

If it's a `div`, you should use JavaScript. You can send a request (using AJAX), or, if the information is short and non-sensitive, you can navigate to the PHP page that does the email sending and add the information to the URL string.

Here is a very quick mock-up of the code. In reality, you should filter inputs and write clean code and whatnot.

Javascript:

```
window.location.href= "http://www.myDomain.com/email.php?data=" + theData ;
```

where *http://www.myDomain.com/email.php* is the url of the php file and *theData* is a variable containing the content of the div.

PHP

```
<?php
  mail("me@myDomain.com", "Content of div", $_GET['data']);  // arguments are: to, subject, body
?>
```

$_GET['data'] is the content sent by the JavaScript above.

I have not included the JavaScript to get the div content into the variable *theData*

Comment: Is there anyway of putting php within a javascript, such as:

function emailForm(){
   var divContent = document.divID.value;
<?php email code here $divContent ?>
}

I am confused on how to go about this.

Comment: The PHP code will run when the page loads (before any JavaScript executes). If the content you want to send is already available, great - You don't need JavaScript here. If the user can change it, you need the code above.

Comment: Yes it will be user changed. This is a great help, Thanks very much. Just to clarify, a question about the body argument in the $_GET request is the ['data'] the name of the DIV?

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden form with a single textarea, set the form method to POST and action as "mailto:;subject:" and then submit it. The contents of the form, i.e. the contents of the DIV in the text area will be part of the body sent out as an email and the default email client on the machine will be opened to actually send the mail.

Comment: I haven't heared of that, but would like to see working live!

Comment: It would still open the email client on the machine and requires user's action to submit the email.

Comment: And it should as hyperlink linking to "mailto:" opens default user email software. If you want to do the sending without a user, only PHP is your choice(if we choose from PHP and JS).

Comment: The DIV is currently in a Form already. If I do this will it send off both forms if I put a form within a form?

Comment: Right, you need the help of a server-side program to do that for you.

Comment: The mail body is composed of contents only from the form controls like INPUT, TEXTAREA, SELECT et., but not from container elements like DIV, SPAN and I guess FORM as well. You can test if the FORM within another FORM will get included if the out FORM is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

This must be done in PHP, as JavaScript has no capability to send an email.

What can you do with JavaScript is - grab DIV contents and send the to PHP script which will send the email.

If you have something like this:

```
<form action="your_php_script.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="body"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Then it will work without AJAX and will redirect you to **your_php_script.php** passing textarea value.

But if you want to send via AJAX, it can be simply done like this and plus some JS code:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   var body = $('input[name="body"]').val();
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'body='+body,
         success: function() {
            alert('Message was sent');
         },
         error: function(error) {
            alert('Error occured: ',error);
         }
      });
   return false;
});
```

And inside your PHP script you grab the value with this:

```
$body = $_POST['body'];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The only problem I have is how i tell PHP what the JavaScript has grabbed? And how do you email it in PHP?

Comment: In PHP I recomment PHPMailer insted of default mail() functionality. And with jQuery you can grab div contents with $('#yourDivID').text() and send it via $.ajax to your PHP script